# How to connect Android device using adb wireless? without any third party tool

Tags: android, adb

How to connect Android device using adb wireless??
As for as adb help says, you just need adb connect, but it seems that's not sufficient as it do not connects device wireless.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect yout device with cable
2. forward abb to tcpip using following command

   adb tcpip 5555
3. disconnect the device
4. connec to to device wireless using following command

   adb connect device_ip:5555